# Return specific columns in jpa for table in join column

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following two tables:

**Table employee**

```
id
name
address
PAN card
Company id ( foreign Key)
```

**Table  Company**

```
id
name
description
Company Registration no
Company CEO name
```

When I write the pojo class for Employee I add the following line:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Company company
```

If I am not wrong, Keeping this object private in Employee class will prevent the details of Company class being send as Json data along with employee data

Now my question is:

- I need only specific Company details (for example company name alone) to be send along with API call to return Employee detail as Json data. But api for company details  should return all the company related information

Comment: did you try with `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: If I put Jsonignore in CompanyDetails. It won't return the data for both Company Details API and Employee details API. But I need the following way: 1. For Company call api all data should be returned for company 2. For employee only specific details of company is required for the employee.

Comment: how are you reading data from DB? Do you use spring-data?

Comment: yes. spring data (crude repository ) is used. Before we were using normal java servlets where mysql procedure calls and queries with JDBC. Now migrating to spring

Comment: you can write a custom impl class for your repository to handle calls for Employee data where you can set what you want to return. Update the question with your repository class

Comment: Thanks. Will try out with custom class. But I feel that is like repeating the same data at two place. Anyways will try out and will get back